# fitted mixed models in the sommer package

Tags: r, statistics, regression, mixed-models, nlme

I have observed in the literature that the `sommer` package brings possibilities associated with the inference of the parameters of a mixed model, in comparison with classic packages: `nlme` or `lme4`.
Due of this, I'm trying to adjust some models via the `mmer()` function, which were previously adjusted via the `lme()` function.

Considering the `nlme` package, the following models have been adjusted:

```
data(Orthodont)
library(nlme)

m1 <- lme(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject, 
               method = "REML")
# Different variances - separate variance per factor level
m2 <- lme(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont, random = list(Subject = pdDiag(~ age)),
               method = "REML")
m3 <- lme(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject, 
               method = "REML")
```

In the `sommer` package, which can be accessed through the link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sommer/sommer.pdf, the following information is said at the end of page 9, beginning of page 10 and of page 47 and
In this link some additional information can also be found: https://rpubs.com/samuelkn/CovarianceStructuresInR:

```
#####===========================================#### 
#####Univariateheterogeneousvariancemodels#### 
#####===========================================#### 
### Compound simmetry(CS)+ Diagonal(DIAG) model 
ans3<-mmer(Yield~Env, random=~Name+vsr(dsr(Env),Name), 
rcov=~vsr(dsr(Env),units), data=DT) 
summary(ans3) 

ans4<-mmec(Yield~Env, random=~Name+vsc(dsc(Env),isc(Name)),
rcov=~vsc(dsc(Env),isc(units)), data=DT)
summary(ans4)
```

On page 38 there is information about the `dsc()` function and page 92 `isc()` function for the diagonal covariance structure. I tried to adjust the models and they looked like this:

```
data(Orthodont)
library(sommer)

m11<- mmer(distance ~ Sex * age, random = ~ vsr(Subject), 
           data = Orthodont, method = "REML")
m22 <- mmer(distance ~ Sex * age, random = ~vsr(dsc(age), isc(Subject)), 
            rcov =~vsr(dsc(age), units),
            data = Orthodont, method = "REML")
m33 <- mmer(distance ~ Sex * age, random = ~ Subject + vsr(age, Subject), 
            data = Orthodont, method = "REML")
```

One fact is that:
**-** For the `m1` and `m11` I obtained satisfactory results:

```
> summary(m1)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Orthodont 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  445.7572 461.6236 -216.8786

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Subject
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.816214 1.386382

Fixed effects:  distance ~ Sex * age 
                  Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)   16.340625 0.9813122 79 16.651810  0.0000
SexFemale      1.032102 1.5374208 25  0.671321  0.5082
age            0.784375 0.0775011 79 10.120823  0.0000
SexFemale:age -0.304830 0.1214209 79 -2.510520  0.0141
 Correlation: 
              (Intr) SexFml age   
SexFemale     -0.638              
age           -0.869  0.555       
SexFemale:age  0.555 -0.869 -0.638

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-3.59804400 -0.45461690  0.01578365  0.50244658  3.68620792 

Number of Observations: 108
Number of Groups: 27 
> summary(m11)
=============================================================
          Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML          
**********************  sommer 4.2  ********************** 
=============================================================
            logLik      AIC      BIC Method Converge
Value -0.008409636 8.016819 18.74534   REML     TRUE
=============================================================
Variance-Covariance components:
                            VarComp VarCompSE Zratio Constraint
u:Subject.distance-distance   3.198   2.76014  1.159   Positive
units.distance-distance       1.914   0.09586 19.966   Positive
=============================================================
Fixed effects:
     Trait        Effect Estimate Std.Error t.value
1 distance   (Intercept)  16.3406   0.97646 16.7346
2 distance     SexFemale   1.0321   1.52982  0.6747
3 distance           age   0.7844   0.07734 10.1422
4 distance SexFemale:age  -0.3048   0.12116 -2.5158
=============================================================
Groups and observations:
          distance
u:Subject       27
=============================================================
Use the '$' sign to access results and parameters
```

**-** For the `m3` and `m33` I obtained satisfactory results
for the fixed part, however for the random part there are still differences, based on the information found in this link of the page 2: https://cran.r-project.org/package=sommer/vignettes/v5.sommer.vs.lme4.pdf :

```
> summary(m3)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Orthodont 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  448.5817 469.7368 -216.2908

Random effects:
 Formula: ~age | Subject
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 2.4055009 (Intr)
age         0.1803455 -0.668
Residual    1.3100396       

Fixed effects:  distance ~ Sex * age 
                  Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)   16.340625 1.0185320 79 16.043311  0.0000
SexFemale      1.032102 1.5957329 25  0.646789  0.5237
age            0.784375 0.0859995 79  9.120691  0.0000
SexFemale:age -0.304830 0.1347353 79 -2.262432  0.0264
 Correlation: 
              (Intr) SexFml age   
SexFemale     -0.638              
age           -0.880  0.562       
SexFemale:age  0.562 -0.880 -0.638

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.168077732 -0.385939009  0.007104087  0.445154545  3.849463576 

Number of Observations: 108
Number of Groups: 27 
> summary(m33)
===============================================================
           Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML           
************************  sommer 4.2  ************************ 
===============================================================
          logLik      AIC      BIC Method Converge
Value -0.1589647 8.317929 19.04645   REML     TRUE
===============================================================
Variance-Covariance components:
                               VarComp VarCompSE Zratio Constraint
Subject.distance-distance     2.434714  1.394632  1.746   Positive
age:Subject.distance-distance 0.009851  0.009058  1.088   Positive
units.distance-distance       2.007921  0.118293 16.974   Positive
===============================================================
Fixed effects:
     Trait        Effect Estimate Std.Error t.value
1 distance   (Intercept)  16.3406   0.97097 16.8291
2 distance     SexFemale   1.0321   1.52122  0.6785
3 distance           age   0.7844   0.08301  9.4493
4 distance SexFemale:age  -0.3048   0.13005 -2.3439
===============================================================
Groups and observations:
            distance
Subject           27
age:Subject       27
===============================================================
Use the '$' sign to access results and parameters
```

Checking random effects m3 and m33:

```
> VarCorr(m3)
Subject = pdLogChol(age) 
            Variance   StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 5.78643477 2.4055009 (Intr)
age         0.03252449 0.1803455 -0.668
Residual    1.71620366 1.3100396       
> sqrt(summary(m33)$varcomp[,1])
[1] 1.55463405 0.08802067 1.36549133
```

However, for model 2, I have been facing problem in structuring this model, compared to the model adjusted via `lme()` ​​function. Note that the models do not exhibit the same coefficients, especially the random effect:

```
> summary(m2)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Orthodont 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  447.1509 465.6617 -216.5755

Random effects:
 Formula: ~age | Subject
 Structure: Diagonal
        (Intercept)        age Residual
StdDev:    1.554607 0.08801657 1.365502

Fixed effects:  distance ~ Sex * age 
                  Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)   16.340625 0.9408690 79 17.367587  0.0000
SexFemale      1.032102 1.4740585 25  0.700177  0.4903
age            0.784375 0.0794421 79  9.873548  0.0000
SexFemale:age -0.304830 0.1244618 79 -2.449182  0.0165
 Correlation: 
              (Intr) SexFml age   
SexFemale     -0.638              
age           -0.858  0.547       
SexFemale:age  0.547 -0.858 -0.638

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.623218206 -0.458236586  0.004989037  0.517505851  3.716965299 

Number of Observations: 108
Number of Groups: 27 
> summary(m22)
===============================================================
           Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML           
************************  sommer 4.2  ************************ 
===============================================================
         logLik     AIC      BIC Method Converge
Value -4.161598 16.3232 27.05172   REML     TRUE
===============================================================
Variance-Covariance components:
                              VarComp VarCompSE Zratio Constraint
age:Subject.distance-distance 0.02684   0.01981  1.355   Positive
age:units.distance-distance   0.19972   0.01017 19.633   Positive
===============================================================
Fixed effects:
     Trait        Effect Estimate Std.Error t.value
1 distance   (Intercept)  16.5180   0.87982 18.7744
2 distance     SexFemale   0.8419   1.37841  0.6108
3 distance           age   0.7682   0.09143  8.4030
4 distance SexFemale:age  -0.2875   0.14324 -2.0075
===============================================================
Groups and observations:
            distance
age:Subject       27
===============================================================
Use the '$' sign to access results and parameters
>
```

The `sommer` package version I am using is:

```
> packageVersion("sommer")
[1] ‘4.3.1’
```

Conclusion: Unfortunately I don't know what could be happening.

Comment: What is the output of `packageVersion("sommer")` ?

Comment: I edited this topic. I updated the sommer version (the last one), some messages stopped appearing but the error still persists.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you decided on the correct way to fit these models in `sommer`? Your link goes to the generic documentation for the package, which doesn't help us decide where to start looking ...

Comment: I improved the information. The problem is now only in the m22 model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model 2 is fitted like this

```
m22 <- mmer(distance ~ Sex * age,
            random = ~  vsr(Subject) + vsr(dsr(age), Subject)  ,
            data = Orthodont)
summary(m22)
sqrt(summary(m22)$varcomp[,1])
```

That returns the same variance components and estimates than the model 2 using lme()

```
# > summary(m22)
# ===============================================================
#   Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML           
# ************************  sommer 4.2  ************************ 
#   ===============================================================
#   logLik      AIC      BIC Method Converge
# Value 0.2963668 7.407266 18.13579     NR     TRUE
# ===============================================================
#   Variance-Covariance components:
#   VarComp VarCompSE Zratio Constraint
# u:Subject.distance-distance   2.416887   1.56526 1.5441   Positive
# age:Subject.distance-distance 0.007748   0.01122 0.6902   Positive
# units.distance-distance       1.864567   0.30408 6.1319   Positive
# ===============================================================
#   Fixed effects:
#   Trait        Effect Estimate Std.Error t.value
# 1 distance   (Intercept)  16.3406   0.94087 17.3676
# 2 distance     SexFemale   1.0321   1.47405  0.7002
# 3 distance           age   0.7844   0.07944  9.8736
# 4 distance SexFemale:age  -0.3048   0.12446 -2.4492
# ===============================================================
#   Groups and observations:
#   distance
# u:Subject         27
# age:Subject       27
# ===============================================================
#   Use the '$' sign to access results and parameters
# > sqrt(summary(m22)$varcomp[,1])
# [1] 1.55463405 0.08802067 1.36549133
```

That is using the mmer() function which uses direct inversion. If you want to use the mmec() function which uses Henderson's approach the model would be:

```
m22 <- mmec(distance ~ Sex * age,
            random = ~  vsc(isc(Subject)) + vsc(dsc(age), isc(Subject))  ,
            # emWeight = rep(1,30),
            data = Orthodont)
summary(m22)$varcomp
sqrt(summary(m22)$varcomp[,1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just noticed that the ````m3```` and ````m33```` don't exhibit the same random effects. Is my specification for the ````m33```` correct in ````sommer````? I updated the topic.

Comment: The model 3 is not possible in sommer, mostly because I am not sure what's the model run behind. In sommer you can fit random slopes, random intercepts, and covariance between random effects. Still, not sure what's the covariance structure behind model 3. Sorry for that.